# How use FFMPEG multi GPU proccess

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, nvidia, multi-gpu

I have a problem and cant find any suitable answer for it.
Its about use multi GPU proccess. 
I have 3 graphic card and you could see it : 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

if image not loaded use this image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/msR83.jpg [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msR83.jpg)

My problem is: when i run more than one ffmpeg command with cuda all process assigned to first GPU. 
like below image: 
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

if image not loaded use this image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfYfz.jpg

you see? all 6 proccess assigned to first GPU. 
I really confused how could i fix it. 

my FFMPEG code is :

```
ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i my-video.mp4 \
  -vf scale_npp=w=426:h=240 -c:v h264_nvenc -profile:v main -b:v 400k -sc_threshold 0 -g 25 \
  -c:a aac -b:a 64k -ar 48000 \
  -f hls -hls_time 6 -hls_playlist_type vod \
  -hls_allow_cache 1 -hls_key_info_file encription.keyinfo \
  -hls_segment_filename f-0-seg-%d.ts f-0.m3u8
```

i run top FFMPEG code for 6 diffrent video at same time. 
please help to find answer. by sharing your knowledge or some links that could help me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Process seems fairly straigh forward from what I can tell:
https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/

> Encoding and decoding work must be explicitly assigned to a GPU when using multiple GPUs in one system. GPUs are identified by their index number; by default all work is performed on the GPU with index 0. Use the following command to obtain a list of all NVIDIA GPUs in the system and their corresponding ID numbers:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -gpu list -f null –
```

> Once you know the index, the -hwaccel_device index flag can be used to set the active GPU for decoding and encoding. In the example below the work will be executed on the gpu with index 1.

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_device 1 -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 5M output.mp4
```

Comment: i read it before. thanks for share it. but do you have any opinion for that i can use all three of my GPU? this tell us we can just use one of them . '-hwaccel_device 0' or '-hwaccel_device 1' or '-hwaccel_device 2'. but i need to use all three.

Comment: can't you simply execute the same code for different files? "ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_device 1 file1.mp4 ..." , then "ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_device 2 file2.mp4 ..."

Comment: but maybe i misunderstood what you are trying to do ...

Comment: No. you undrestand my problem. and your opinion is one way to solve this problem. but im looking for one answe that automaticlly do this. i think it should be a way to tell ffmpeg or cuda do this for us. that they automaticlly load balance betwwen those three GPU.

Comment: I think the answer is in "work must be explicitly assigned to a GPU when using multiple GPUs in one system". This does not seem possible, but you could write a bash or python script that goes through all files in a folder, assigns an index, and executes the above command  with -hwaccel_device fileindex%numberofGPUs

Comment: Ok. thank you for good opinion. if find better way tell me. Thanks and good luck

Comment: Why dont you split the file in three, sizes varyying according to gpu performance and then encode all of them at once and then join the files ? Is there a overhead joining the files ?